# Deploy Azure Batch via ARM template with application upload

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-batch

I built out an Azure Batch Account via the UI (Portal) and exported the template after I got everything working the way I wanted it.

Now I'm trying to deploy this ARM template via Visual Studio 2019 and keep getting the following error:

```
The specified application package does not exist.
```

The ARM template looks good and I've reconciled it with [Microsoft.Batch batchAccounts/pools template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.batch/2019-04-01/batchaccounts/pools). I did this to verify that the template allows for applicationPackages element.

The specific portion of the template causing my issue is as follows:

```
        "applicationPackages": [
      {
        "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', parameters('batchAccounts_baeast909_name')), '/applications/logparser')]",
        "version": "2.2"
      },
      {
        "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', parameters('batchAccounts_baeast909_name')), '/applications/powershellscripts')]",
        "version": "1.0"
      }
    ]
```

I was hoping this is would be as simple as placing the application zips in a directory called applications and running everything again. Alas it wasn't and the deployment failed with the same error.

One of the comments asked why I would be doing this.  The answer to this is I'm running a Custom Activity out of Azure Data Factory V2 (ADFv2.) The custom activity transforms WebLogs via a executable called LogParser.exe  That executable is loaded as an application to the Batch Account as you see below.  I also added the PowerShell Scripts that tie everything together as an application.

[image: Applications loaded to Batch Account]

I was hoping for a solution similar to deploying a Web App that is detailed here: [Deploy Azure Web App Package using ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665559/deploy-azure-web-app-package-using-arm)

So my questions are:
Can the applications zips be deployed at the same time as I am deploying the ARM template?
If they can not, when do I deploy them, and how do I automate that process?

application.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "configuration": {
      "type": "object",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Configuration for this resource"
      }
    },
    "pools_1_password": {
      "type": "SecureString"
    },
    "batchAccounts_baeast909_name": {
      "defaultValue": "baeast909",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "storageAccounts_storageaccount909_externalid": {
      "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/subguid/resourceGroups/resourcegroup909/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccount909",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('batchAccounts_baeast909_name')]",
      "location": "eastus2",
      "tags": {
        "displayname": "[parameters('configuration').displayName]",
        "department": "[parameters('configuration').department]",
        "group": "[parameters('configuration').group]",
        "environment": "[parameters('configuration').environment]",
        "primaryOwner": "[parameters('configuration').primaryOwner]",
        "secondaryOwner": "[parameters('configuration').secondaryOwner]",
        "version": "[parameters('configuration').version]",
        "ms-resource-usage": "azure-cloud-shell"
      },
      "properties": {
        "autoStorage": {
          "storageAccountId": "[parameters('storageAccounts_storageaccount909_externalid')]"
        },
        "poolAllocationMode": "BatchService"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/pools",
      "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('batchAccounts_baeast909_name'), '/1')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', parameters('batchAccounts_baeast909_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "vmSize": "STANDARD_A1",
        "interNodeCommunication": "Disabled",
        "maxTasksPerNode": 1,
        "taskSchedulingPolicy": {
          "nodeFillType": "Spread"
        },
        "deploymentConfiguration": {
          "virtualMachineConfiguration": {
            "imageReference": {
              "publisher": "microsoftwindowsserver",
              "offer": "windowsserver",
              "sku": "2016-datacenter",
              "version": "latest"
            },
            "nodeAgentSkuId": "batch.node.windows amd64",
            "dataDisks": [
              {
                "lun": 0,
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "diskSizeGB": 100,
                "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "scaleSettings": {
          "fixedScale": {
            "targetDedicatedNodes": 1,
            "targetLowPriorityNodes": 0,
            "resizeTimeout": "PT15M"
          }
        },
        "userAccounts": [
          {
            "name": "jborn",
            "elevationLevel": "NonAdmin",
            "password": "[parameters('pools_1_password')]"
          }
        ],
        "applicationPackages": [
          {
            "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', parameters('batchAccounts_baeast909_name')), '/applications/logparser')]",
            "version": "2.2"
          },
          {
            "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', parameters('batchAccounts_baeast909_name')), '/applications/powershellscripts')]",
            "version": "1.0"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

application.parameters.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "configuration": {
      "value": {
        "displayName": "A Batch Account",
        "department": "IT",
        "group": "Development",
        "environment": "dev",
        "primaryOwner": "user1@fred.com",
        "secondaryOwner": "user2@fred.com",
        "version": "1.0"
      }
    },
    "pools_1_password": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/subguid/resourceGroups/rgn00119/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvault909"
        },
        "secretName": "azureAdmin"
      }
    },
    "batchAccounts_jc00mdpbageu2d99_name": {
      "value": "jc00mdpbageu2d99"
    },
    "storageAccounts_jc00mdpstgeud99_externalid": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/subguid/resourceGroups/rgn00119/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageAccount909"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is ```application package```?

Comment: Why are you trying to deploy application zips with batch account?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to download and deploy an ARM template using Visual Studio 2019:

1. Fill the details for creating a Azure Batch account and click on "Download a template for automation"

[image]

2. Download the zip

[image]

- Deploy ARM template using Visual Studio 2019

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy
- In step 4 in the above document use a blank template instead of a WebApp

  [image]
- Now paste the contents from the downloaded zip

  Copy contents from `template.json` to `azuredeploy.json`

  Copy contents from `parameters.json` to `azuredeploy.parameters.json`
- Now deploy your ARM template using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy#azurerm-module-script

Edit: In order to create a batch pool using ARM template, you would first have to create an Application Package using Azure CLI and reference this from your ARM template for creating a Batch Pool

```
# Upload and register your archive as application package
az batch application package create \
  --resource-group testrg01 \
  --name test01 \
  --application-id app01 \
  --package-file myapp-exe.zip \
  --version 1.0
# Set this version of package as default version
az batch application set \
  --resource-group testrg01 \
  --name test01 \
  --application-id app01 \
  --default-version 1.0
```

References:

https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2017/12/12/essential-azure-batch-with-azure-cli/

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/cli/azure/batch/application/package?view=azure-cli-latest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-cli-templates

Hope this helps!

Comment: The only portion of this that addresses how to deploy application packages via a template is the last bullet - even then it is a deployment to a web application not a generic application package. My application packages that I'm trying to deploy along with the Azure Batch Service are the following:  PowerShell scripts, and LogParser.exe.  Both are manually uploaded as zips using the Azure UI portal.  Most of your reply is detailing out how to extract the template from the portal which I already did. My template has references to applicationPackages that need to exist for deployment to succeed.

Comment: Please share your ARM template in the question

Comment: added complete application.json and application.parameters.json.  Removed PII information with manual updates to both, but otherwise is the code that I'm trying to deploy

Comment: Thank you for adding all the relevant information. I have edited my answer to provide more context. Thanks!